# $U_{(1)}\overset{p}{\to} 0$ from a $U(0,1)$ population

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification

Let $U_1, \dots, U_n$ be independent uniform $[0, 1]$ random variables. I wish to show that the first order statistic
$$U_{(1)}\overset{p}{\to}0$$
(with respect to convergence in probability). I have already shown that $U_{(1)}$ is beta-distributed with parameters $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = n$.

Is this a valid solution?

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then by the [Markov inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov's_inequality#Statement),
$$\mathbb{P}(|U_{(1)}| \geq \epsilon) \leq \dfrac{\mathbb{E}[|U_{(1)}|]}{\epsilon} = \dfrac{\mathbb{E}[U_{(1)}]}{\epsilon}$$
since $\mathbb{E}[|U_{(1)}|] = \mathbb{E}[U_{(1)}]$ given the support of the $U_i$ in $[0, 1]$, and then we have 
$$\mathbb{P}(|U_{(1)}| \geq \epsilon) \leq \dfrac{\mathbb{E}[|U_{(1)}|]}{\epsilon} = \dfrac{\mathbb{E}[U_{(1)}]}{\epsilon} = \dfrac{1}{(n+1)\epsilon}\to 0$$
as $n \to \infty$, hence $U_{(1)}\overset{p}{\to}0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me, except I would also write $$\Pr[|U_{(1)} - 0| \ge \epsilon] = \Pr[|U_{(1)}| \ge \epsilon] = \ldots,$$ hence $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \Pr[|U_{(1)} - 0| \ge \epsilon] \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)\epsilon} = \frac{1}{\epsilon} \cdot 0 = 0$$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, and since the probability is by definition bounded below by $0$, the limit must equal $0$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.